# Javafx-Image To PDF Conversion Displaying Half of the Image Using PDFBox

Tags: java, javafx, pdfbox

I have successfully converted an Image to Pdf. My issue is that the pdf is displaying half of the width
My Code:

```
@FXML
private void print() {
    try {
        WritableImage nodeshot = stackPane.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
        File file = new File("C:/Users/Andre Kelvin/Desktop/TheNode.png");
        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(nodeshot, null), "png", file);

        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        PDImageXObject pdimage;
        PDPageContentStream content;

        pdimage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("C:/Users/Andre Kelvin/Desktop/TheNode.png", doc);
        content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        content.drawImage(pdimage, 0, 0);
        content.close();
        doc.addPage(page);
        doc.save("C:/Users/Andre Kelvin/Desktop/PDFNode.pdf");
        doc.close();
        file.delete();

        //This Line Automatically Opens the user defualt pdf file viewer
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + "C:/Users/Andre Kelvin/Desktop/PDFNode.pdf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I have tried getting the root node width and height by using this line:

```
content.drawImage(pdimage, 0, 0,(float)stackPane.getPrefWidth(),(float)stackPane.getPrefHeight());
```

and this:

```
content.drawImage(pdimage, 0, 0,(float)stackPane.getMaxWidth(),(float)stackPane.getMaxHeight());
```

it will just display a blank white page.

This is the actual image that is Converted to pdf:
[image]

And this is the pdf of the image:
[image]

Comment: Please share the PDF and the original image and tell what PDFBox version you are using. For width and height, use the image sizes, and multiply them by a factor to get the appropriate size. Also check whether the png file that you are saving and deleting (why?) is correct.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr see edit. am using pdfbox 2.0.12 and the png image has no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the preferred size properties nor their min/max counterparts allow you to reliably determine the size of a `Region`. Those are just indicators and the calculated values may not match. Furthermore the `Region` may be resized to sizes other than the preferred size. Last but not least those properties may contain special values `Region.USE_PREF_SIZE`(=`Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`) and `Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`(=`-1`) and even do so by default.

If you need to get the size of a node, use the `boundsInLocal` property:

```
Bounds bounds = stackPane.getBoundsInLocal();
```

In this case it's simpler to get the size of the snapshot instead though.

Furthermore the page size of the `PDPage` may not be large enough to contain the whole image. You need to scale the image instead or change the page size of the `PDPage`.

---

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + "C:/Users/Andre Kelvin/Desktop/PDFNode.pdf");
```

This can be done platform-independent using the [`HostServices` available via the `Application` instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getHostServices--).

#### Example

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button button = new Button("print");
    StackPane root = new StackPane(button);
    button.setOnAction(evt -> {
        try {
            WritableImage nodeshot = root.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
            
            // store image in-memory
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(nodeshot, null), "png", output);
            output.close();

            PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            PDImageXObject pdimage;
            PDPageContentStream content;

            pdimage = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(doc, output.toByteArray(), "png");
            content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

            // fit image to media box of page
            PDRectangle box = page.getMediaBox();
            double factor = Math.min(box.getWidth() / nodeshot.getWidth(), box.getHeight() / nodeshot.getHeight());

            float height = (float) (nodeshot.getHeight() * factor);
            
            // beware of inverted y axis here
            content.drawImage(pdimage, 0, box.getHeight() - height, (float) (nodeshot.getWidth() * factor), height);

            content.close();
            doc.addPage(page);

            File outputFile = new File("C:/Users/Andre Kelvin/Desktop/PDFNode.pdf");

            doc.save(outputFile);
            doc.close();

            getHostServices().showDocument(outputFile.toURI().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: You are using the factor for the width but not for the height, I wonder if this will look good.

Comment: this worked ok. but it added some height below the pdf image.